# volumetric slice plot gone wrong

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

Here is my code:

```
xslice = [bestcoefs(1), cc1(no1)]; 
yslice = [bestcoefs(2), cc2(no2)];
zslice = [cc3(1), bestcoefs(3)]; 
slice(V, xslice, yslice, zslice, 'linear');
cb = colorbar; 
xlabel('c1'); ylabel('c2'); zlabel({'likelihood of (c1,c2,c3)','c3'});
view(3);
```

`V` is a matrix of probabilities 6x13x9 and `bestcoefs(1)`, `cc1(no1)`, etc. are points where I want to slice the plot.  However, I get this result:

[image: wrong]

Why does it come out like this? I want it to look like [the first one here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html).

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] of your question? Giving some values for all variables (as I did in my answer below) that still cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run:

```
% some data:
V = randn(6,13,9);
bestcoefs = randi(6,3,1);
cc = randi(6,3,1);

% your code with slight modifications:
xslice = [bestcoefs(1), cc(1)]; 
yslice = [bestcoefs(2), cc(2)];
zslice = [cc(1), bestcoefs(3)]; 
slice(V, xslice, yslice, zslice, 'linear');
cb = colorbar; 
xlabel('c1'); ylabel('c2');...
    zlabel({'likelihood of (c1,c2,c3)','c3'});
view(3);
```

I get something like this:

[image]

Which looks fine to me. Try to see if your `bestcoefs`, `cc`'s and `no`'s are defined correctly.

Comment: sorry for the late reply...still didn't work. The bestcoefs ccs are right. I printed them and they are indeed inside the limits of the axes. Though the plot comes out as the first one. Has anyone had this problem before? I have matlab2015a. Your code with your matrix works ok for me too

Comment: @ourania well I can only repeat my asking from the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196737/volumetric-slice-plot-gone-wrong/45201515#comment77479301_45196737), that you provide a [mcve].